# Why was this made CW?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

Looking at [Q: Pros and cons of hibernating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4571/pros-and-cons-of-hibernating), I wonder why it was made Community Wiki? To me, it doesn't look subjective, nor is it like a poll.

Answer (score 2):

It's a list "question", since there really is no "real" answer to that. More along the lines of "It might or might not work", "Depends on your hardware" etc.

Comment: It's not really a list question - I don't see any reason for there not to be a single clear answer.

Comment: @fluteflute The title is "Pros and cons of hibernating" - in my experience, the pros and cons of that subject are very subjective, based off of your hardware configuration.